# How to use php variables in MJML

Tags: mjml

anybody any idea how to use php variables in [MJML](https://mjml.io/documentation) using the https://github.com/juanmiguelbesada/mjml-php library? Thanks

```
$greeting = 'Hello World';

    <mjml>
      <mj-body>
        <mj-section>
          <mj-column>

            <mj-image width="100px" src="/assets/img/logo-small.png"></mj-image>

            <mj-divider border-color="#F45E43"></mj-divider>

            <mj-text font-size="20px" color="#F45E43" font-family="helvetica"><?=$greeting?></mj-text>

          </mj-column>
        </mj-section>
      </mj-body>
    </mjml>
```

Answer (score 0):

> There is no mention of any templating language in the documentation
> simply because there isn't any built-in templating language in MJML
> (and never has been). You're indeed confusing MJML with Mailjet's
> template language.
>
> MJML is a markup language aimed at making it easy to create responsive
> emails.
>
> For templating, you're free to use any template language of your
> choice.

[source and examples](https://github.com/mjmlio/mjml/issues/1403#issuecomment-433833812)